# Monit not able to start program in screen

Tags: bash, monit

I have monit able to watch the program but the start script is not working. The stop script works just fine.

The when monit tries to start it, it just says execution failed.

Monit part

```
check process tsdnsserver
  matching "tsdnsserver"
  start program = "/bin/bash -c '/root/ts3/tsdns/stop.sh'"
  stop program = "/bin/bash -c '/root/ts3/tsdns/stop.sh'"
  if failed port 41144 type tcp then restart
  if 2 restarts within 3 cycles then timeout
```

Start Script

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -dmS tsdns ./tsdnsserver 41144
```

Stop Script

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -X -S tsdns kill
```

Comment: Does the start script work when you run it manually from the command line ? Does the 'start program' command run when you are in /tmp for example ?

Comment: Is here any relevant information in your logs ?

Comment: @lain This is the error I get when I try to use monit to start it.

`[UTC May 27 06:04:25] error    : M/Monit handler failed, retry scheduled for next cycle
[UTC May 27 06:04:25] info     : 'tsdnsserver' start: /root/ts3/tsdns/start.sh
`
I am not sure what you mean to start it in /tmp

I an run the script manually.

Comment: both the start and stop lines in the "monit part" show stop.sh... is this correct?

Comment: @peter That was my fault on my copying kunfu. I am not sure why monit can run the stop script just fine but the start one wont work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what happened. I was able to change my start line to

```
start program = "/bin/bash -c 'screen -dmS tsdns /root/ts3/tsdns/tsdnsserver 41144'"
```

It now works for whatever reason